# Is this the right way to deal with Javascript immutability?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutability, immutable.js

So I'm trying to build a React-Electron game and I've been having a headache with how to deal with immutability properly.

As an example, let's say my game is a trading game. My state would be something like this:

```
this.state = {
  player: new Trader(),
  customer: new Trader()
}
```

And the Trader class is a custom reusable class that handles different traders:

```
class Trader {
  constructor() {
    // Array of inventories that the trader have
    this.inventory = [];
    this.cash = 0;
  }

  addItemToInventory(item) {
    this.inventory.push(item);
  }
}
```

Right away we can see a problem with `addItemToInventory`. If I call it within the Component like:

```
this.state.player.addItemToInventory({ name: 'Apple', price: 10 });
```

This would be an antipattern since I'm trying to directly mutate the React state, right?

So after doing some research, I have come up with a solution: an `Immutable` masterclass:

```
class Immutable {
  getClone() {
    return Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(this)), this);
  }
}
```

The `getClone` function will return an object that carries all prototype functions and all properties of the previous object, in other words, a perfect shallow copy. Simply returning a spread object like `return { ...this }` will not include all the prototype functions and the code will break.

For any kind of data that needs to interact with React state or Redux, I can extend it to Immutable like:

```
class Trader extends Immutable {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.inventory = [];
    this.cash = 0;
  }

  addItemToInventoryThenGet(item) {
    const newInventory = [ ...this.inventory ];
    newInventory.push(item);
    return Object.assign(this.getClone(), { inventory: newInventory });
  }
}
```

And every time an item is added to a trader's inventory, I would use setState to overwrite the entire Trader instance:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
  return { 
    player: prevState.player.addItemToInventoryThenGet({
      name: 'Apple',
      price: 10
    }) 
  } 
});
```

Of course, this code works perfectly in my project and it satisfies the immutable law of React and Redux. However, I don't see this kind of pattern being discussed too much. So, to React/Redux experts, am I doing this the right way? Is there any kind of hidden performance problem or bottlenecks that I need to be aware of?

Also, do I need to use something like `Immutable.js` or `immutability-helper`, or should this way be fine?

Comment: Perhaps https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This won't be a direct answer but I think this is where we use components instead of classes in React so much. Can't you create your `Player` and `Customer` as components? Or one component perhaps?

Comment: I will have to use Trader class to write the game rules code so it can't be a Component :) But interesting suggestion!

Comment: @mplungjan I think my question is not just a code review but rather a universal question about dealing with Javascript immutability. I really need to know whether I should apply this pattern to all my React code since I really dislike dependencies like Immutable.js. But thank's for the suggestion!

Comment: I would make the Trader constructor take arguments, then you can just `return new Trader(this.cash, [...this.inventory, item])`, but I'm not familiar with React and maybe that makes no sense....

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for your suggestion! Well the issue is not a React thing, but let's say I have two subclasses `Customer extends Trader` and `Player extends Trader`, then I have to do something like `if (this instanceof Customer) { return new Customer(/* yada yada */) } else { return new Player(  /* yada yada */)}`, right? Not to mention my actual Trader class is a huge class with 10 - 15 fields so I would have to pass all of them into the constructor.

Comment: I'm not very experienced with classes and even JS itself but why it can't be a component? :) Maybe this is a very simple explanation but: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Comment: @devserkanThere are many reasons why it can't be a Component but I'll give you the most simple one. When I want to save the game, I need to parse the player's Trader instance into a JSON file so that it carries all the player's metadata at the point where I save the game. So, it needs to be a data object instead of a component.

Comment: Yes, sorry, you can just do `new this(...)` I believe, if you want to support inheritance. And well, if you have a lot of arguments then I think the best solution is just to pass them. I am of the Python mindset, though, where explicit is better than implicit

Comment: @PhiHong, thank you for the explanation. But, can't we keep those metadata, etc in the state? I am asking this just for curiosity and to get better knowledge.

Comment: Sorry, `new this.constructor(...)` ugh, shoehorning class-based inheritance into a prototype-based language is ugly for sure...

Comment: @devserkan Well for one, `this.state: { player: new Trader() }` is exactly the same as `this.state: { player: { inventory: [], cash: 0 } }` so technically we are still keeping the metadata in state. I need to keep it as a Class so I can pass them easily to the 'game rules' code. Let's just say designing a management game's mechanics is really complex so I need to keep it simple.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's actually a great way O.O. But, well, for one, `getClone()` could be useful if I want to use it outside the class. Also, you have to write it like `return new this.constructor(Object.assign({}, this, { inventory: newInventory }))` if you want to avoid passing 10 - 15 parameters to the argument. By doing that, you will be creating a new Trader reference, and then also create a new reference with Object.assign. That would be a bit counterproductive right? What do you think?